# :.w !bash a temporarily modified line and executing it in the shell

Tags: substitute, comments, bash, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# scp /tmp/abc.sh SERVER1:~/bin && ssh SERVER1 "~/bin/abc.sh"
echo "Hello Stack Exchange"
echo "thanks for the help
```

I would like to be able to use a keyboard mapping to be able to do `<leader>r` when my cursor is on line 2 and run the command in the bash shell.  To do this, I need to be able to remove the `#` at the start of line two.  `:.w` writes the whole line and it appears there is no way to use `:w ! bash` on a partial line.  I've also tried `:.w !sed "s/^# \(.*\)/\1/"` but sed appears to have a problem with the `#` as part of command (E194).

It seems this should be relatively easy but I'm at my wits end.  I'm running a Mac with Bash 5.2.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Funny I didn't think of this earlier, but the easiest solutions is to just put a multiple line bash comment at the start of the file and then have my little macros be one per line and execute them normally.

Comment: Bash doesn't really have multiline comments so be careful with that strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can't feed a partial line to `:w !` or any other Ex command.

But you can use a bunch of vimscript functions to get a functionally identical outcome:

```
nnoremap <leader>r <Cmd>echo system('bash', substitute(getline('.'), '^#*\s*', '', ''))<CR>
```

- `:help getline()` grabs the content of the given line(s), here it is the content of the current line,
- `:help substitute()` changes whatever needs to be changed in the given line, here we remove eventual leading comment and whitespace, which makes the mapping work the same on commented and uncommented lines,
- the result is passed to `:help system()` as input.

Note that quoting and escaping issues are easy to come by when dealing with the shell. I would recommend you read `help system()` carefully.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  I'll have a read of the system documentation as it will help me get a better grasp of what is going on.  I'll comment more once I've given it a try.

Comment: It works perfectly.  Many thanks!  Since I'm new and don't have any reputation I can't vote the answer up, but if/when I can I will.